# AngularJS Mongoose findOne OK but save error :DocumentNotFoundError:

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

On client.save() below, I have the following error (which is catch properly):

DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: '5bfbce595be7d1047c976e6b' }"

```
app.put('/api/client', function (req, res) {
    Client.findOne(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body._id)).then(client => {
            //This is OK, I can see client and its properties
            client.name = req.body.name;
            //This is OK, I can see the updated client and its properties
            client.save().then(test => {
                console.log("ERR=" + err);
                console.log(test);
            }).catch(err => console.log("ERR :" + err));
            res.json(client);
        });
});
```

The model is as such:

```
 mongoose.model('Client', {
    _id: {type: String, default: ''},
    name: {type: String, default: ''},
    creationDate: {type: Date, default: ''}
});
```

How come the document is found on FindOne() and no more on save()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do so:

```
 mongoose.model('Client', {
  _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, auto: true },
  name: { type: String, default: '' },
  creationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});
```

And

```
Client.findOne().where({_id : req.body._id})...
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thank you very much!